# Cannot perform a calling between two emulator in android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

I turned on two emulators with port 5556 and 5554 from different windows. I pressed number 5556 and called. But nothing happens. I cannot call between two emulators in Android studio 2.0. How can I fix it Thank all
In addition, can I use block function to block a virtual call?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if calling between two emulators should work or not. You can simulate phone call in another way:

1. Select … in the emulator panel.
2. Select "Phone" in the left panel of the Extended Controls dialog.
3. Select or type a phone number in the From field.
4. Click Call Device.